# Selecting Data from multiple tables using IN and Subquery

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables in SQL Server:

1. Pay
2. Allowances
3. Deductions

All of them have following columns: empID, Amount.

I am writing a query to select amounts from all three tables using IN. Following is my query

```
Select sum(P.Amount), sum(A.Amount), sum(D.Amount)
from Pay P, Allowances A, Deductions D
where P.empID=A.empID=D.empID IN (Select EmpId from Employees)
```

Basically I want to get Pay, Allowance and Deductions of each employee one by one. But I cannot get the query correct.

Comment: After you've got to grips with basic clauses like JOIN and UNION, if you're still struggling, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Hi @Strawberry thank you for the response. Basically I want to get Pay, Allowance and Deductions of employees one by one using their employee IDs one by one (picked from inner query). Then i will pass this information to a crystal report. I have modified the question as well. Thanks again

Comment: I can only refer you to my earlier comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need an UNION ALL query:

```
SELECT empID, 'Pay' AS fromtable, Amount
FROM Pay
WHERE empID IN (1200,1201)
UNION ALL
SELECT empID, 'Allowances' AS fromtable, Amount
FROM Allowances
WHERE empID IN (1200,1201)
UNION ALL
SELECT empID,  'Deductions' AS fromtable, Amount
FROM Deductions
WHERE empID IN (1200,1201)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I will use the results for crystal reports. But what if I am using subquery inside the IN clause.  Like IN (select empID from EMIdTable) will all the tables return correct amounts for the same ID one by one?